# How to check if stored procedure returns data or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure `GetLastRecordId()` in SQL Server which returns the last record id in controller of ASP.NET MVC project. But the problem is that when there is no data in the table, it shows a result like below so I can't check against null:

[image]

My stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetLastRecordId] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        CustomerCreditAppId, CompanyName 
    FROM
        tblname 
    WHERE
        CustomerCreditAppId = (SELECT MAX(CustomerCreditAppId) FROM tblname)
END
```

Comment: Expand the results view and re-upload your screenshot maybe? Also, copy/paste the stored procedure and add corresponding tag?

Comment: I cannot see anything in this screenshot :-)

Comment: I have expanded the result and just uploaded new screenshot @Rafalon

Comment: The debugger may be your problem here. Evaluating a Linq query in the debugger can change the results that you get when it's executed in code. Note the " results ... cannot be enumerated more than once" message.

Comment: This is a dreadful idea. You set your PK field to be auto-incremented, not attempt to set it yourself (if multiple users are making a request at the same time, they will all get the same value)

Comment: SELECT @@IDENTITY you can use. . (SELECT MAX(CustomerCreditAppId) FROM tblname) if your colum is identity incremented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Any to check if the Enumerable is not empty:

> spdata.Any()

Comment: That is giving me below exception message.  'spdata.Any()' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' bool {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: Is there an `InnerException`?

Comment: Could you show us the content of GetLastRecordId please ?